# How do I set the Cancel property inside OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

I've created a sub class of ActionFilterAttribute and I want to set the Cancel property.  It's not a member of the base class, it's not a member of the ActionExecutingContext, so where is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this property was removed in Beta.  Just set the Result property to some non-null value will have the same effect.  See http://forums.asp.net/t/1337873.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've actually written a blog post closely related to this topic with some code samples, available here: http://andrewlocatelliwoodcock.com/2011/12/15/canceling-the-actionexecutingcontext-in-the-onactionexecuting-actionfilter/